# HDMI Slow | Ubuntu 20.10 | Dell Precision M4600

Tags: dell, hdmi

I'm having a weird problem where Ubuntu is running extremely slow if I run it through an external screen through HDMI. However, the weird part is this:

- If I run only on the monitor, through HDMI (and disable the laptop), it runs slow.
- If I mirror the screen, it runs FINE.
- If I mirror the screen BUT CLOSE THE LAPTOP, it runs slow again.

*And of course if I just run Ubuntu on the laptop, it runs super fast, because it's an i7 with 8 cores and 16GB ram.

I can't figure out why on earth this is happening.

Note: It's only happening on this one computer which is a Dell Precision M4600. I have a heap of laptops around here (9 all up).. and I have tried the top dozen or so Linux distributions over the last year or two, and I've never really encountered such a problem. Most Linux distributions handle HDMI screens without an issue. But with THIS laptop, I am also having HDMI issues with MX Linux and Manjaro. So I know it's not necessarily an Ubuntu problem IT's more to do with the actual laptop. If anything, Ubuntu is giving me the best possible outcome, because it is at least working while mirrored. MX Linux didn't work at all. Manjaro worked fine, but it wouldn't let me close laptop lid.

What I am trying to do is just have Ubuntu run through the HDMI screen, then go into power settings and change everything to "do nothing" when the laptop is closed or it becomes idle, etc, and then I can just use the HDMI/screen exclusively. But the problem I am having with Ubuntu is as soon as I close the lid, Ubuntu continues to work, but EXTREMELY slow. like several seconds passes before anything happens after every click

I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

After installing different drivers with limited success, I think it has something to do with Nvidia. I officially give up. I'm gonna put Windows back on this computer and sell it.